# I cant seem to assign a pointer an array and then change the contents of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I couldn't figure out how to make a function return an array so instead I decided to try and pass an empty array (of the correct size) into my function and than reassign the address to a different array of the same size. Is this at all a way to do things??? Can someone show me what to do? if this is wrong can you fill me in on how to do this?

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void ArrayFiller(int earray,int s, int f){
    int *ptrarray = &earray;
    int prenum_size = std::abs(s) + f - 1;
    int pre_num[prenum_size];
    for(int x=s;x<f;x++){
        pre_num[x+std::abs(s)] = x;
    }
    *ptrarray = pre_num;
}


int Main(){
    int first = -10;
    int second = 15;
    int temp[abs(first) + abs(second)];
    ArrayFiller(temp, first, second);


    int n = sizeof(temp)/sizeof(temp[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << temp[i] << ' ';
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile as is: `ArrayFiller`'s first parameter is an `int`, but you're giving it an array.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel how do i make the first parameter an array. Would i do int earray[] ?

Comment: You could, although since array parameters declared in that manner are really just pointers, you could just declare it as `int* earray` and not even have to declare `ptrarray` in that function.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel with the code: ```void ArrayFiller(int* earray,int s, int f){

 int prenum_size = std::abs(s) + f - 1;
 int pre_num[prenum_size];
 for(int x=s;x<f;x++){
  pre_num[x+std::abs(s)] = x;
 }
 earray = pre_num;
}
``` I get no errors in the ide but it still wont build

Comment: `Main` is supposed to be `main`?

Comment: Btw VLA is not legal in C++ just use `std::vector`

Comment: `temp[abs(first) + abs(second)]` is not standard C++. C++ doesn't support VLA (but some compilers do as extension), so you should avoid them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void ArrayFiller(int earray[],int s, int f){
    for(int x=s;x<f;x++){
        earray[x+(std::abs(s))] = x;
    }
}

int main(){
    int first = -10;
    int second = 15;
    int n = abs(first)+abs(second);

    int* temp = new int[n];
    ArrayFiller(temp, first, second);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << temp[i] << ' ';
    }

    delete [] temp;

    return 0;
}
```